# Html summary-element click disabling on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a details-element that has a summary-element inside it

```
<details open>
    <summary>Hello</summary>
    <p>World!</p>
</details>
```

Then I have a listener for clikcing summary-element, like

```
summaryListener(event) {
    if (someClause()) {return false;}
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

On Chrome browser, details-element won't close when summary is clicked, but on Firefox, that code seems to have no impact on details-element's behaviour. Why? And how can I prevet details-element from closing when summary is clicked? And why Firefox seems to handle details opening and closing despite preventDefault and stopPropagation is declared/called to event.

Comment: is this the complete code?

Comment: Relevant parts of it

Comment: Both are giving same results.detail is not closing